Durable Task SQL Provider - The listener for function 'MyFunction' was unable to start
I'm trying to use the Durable Task SQL Provider and I have it working fine locally, but once deployed to Azure the orchestration starts but it just stays in pending status. The logs show a Sql Exception with login failed when trying to start the listener. (I'll put the full exception below.)
The function is C# .NET 8 Isolated
Using Azure SQL database
I had to run the scripts to create the durable tasks manually.
The login has db_owner as well as dt_runtime roles
It is able to call dt.CreateInstance and insert to dt.NewEvents, dt.Instances and dt.Payloads
The exception I'm seeing in the logs is below, and I'm getting it for all Activities when I call the orchestrator:
2024-09-13T12:50:46.523 [Error] The listener for function 'Functions.Activity_CheckConnections' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException : The listener for function 'Functions.Activity_CheckConnections' was unable to start. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout,Boolean allowCreate,Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async DurableTask.SqlServer.SqlDbManager.EnsureDatabaseExistsAsync() at /_/src/DurableTask.SqlServer/SqlDbManager.cs : 183
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async DurableTask.SqlServer.SqlDbManager.AcquireDatabaseLockAsync(Boolean createDatabaseIfNotExists) at /_/src/DurableTask.SqlServer/SqlDbManager.cs : 137
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async DurableTask.SqlServer.SqlDbManager.CreateOrUpgradeSchemaAsync(Boolean recreateIfExists) at /_/src/DurableTask.SqlServer/SqlDbManager.cs : 33
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskExtension.StartTaskHubWorkerIfNotStartedAsync() at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\DurableTaskExtension.cs : 1414
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(??) at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs : 68
   End of inner exception```



My hosts.json is:

```{
    "version": "2.0",
    "functionTimeout": "-1",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning",
            "DurableTask.SqlServer": "Debug",
            "DurableTask.Core": "Debug"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "hubName": "ICHub",
            "storageProvider": {
                "type": "mssql",
                "connectionStringName": "IgniteDBConnString",
                "taskEventLockTimeout": "00:02:00",
                "createDatabaseIfNotExists": true,
                "schemaName": "dt"
            }
        }
    }
}

How would it be able to insert to those tables but fail to log in when starting the listeners?
EDIT: Tracing through the code for the SQL Provider, it's trying to connect to the master database to check if my database exists. This seems like a bug since it's not guaranteed the application will have access to master.

How do you manage the database connection? Connection string with password, managed identity? This error is quite clear Login failed for user ''

"Active Directory Default" and again it is able to connect, it calls the initial stored procedure and inserts into several tables.

This is a bug in the durable task provider. I've submitted a bug report for it: https://github.com/microsoft/durabletask-mssql/issues/233
